# Convert Surface of Revolution to Parametric Equations

Tags: calculus, geometry, solid-of-revolution

Is there any method that to convert a surface obtained by revolving a function around the x or y axis into a parametric equation?

For example:
The function $y = x^3$ for $-3 < x < 3$ when revolved around the y axis forms a bowl like shape. Is there any way to express this surface, or any similar surface as a set of parametric equations?

[image: $y = x^3$ revolved around the y axis]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any surface of revolution can be easily parametrized. If you start with the parametric curve $(x(u),y(u))$, $u\in I$ (some interval), and rotate it about the $x$-axis, the surface you obtain will be parametrized by
$$g(u,v) = \big(x(u), y(u)\cos v, y(u)\sin v\big), \qquad u\in I, \quad v\in [0,2\pi).$$